# Can't dismiss DialogFragment after clicking the button very quickly (Android)

Tags: java, android, android-dialogfragment

I have a `DialogFragment` with a simple `cancel` button on it.
What I want to do is to dismiss the dialog everytime after pressing the cancel button.
However, I found that if I click the button very quickly once the dialog opened,
the `dismiss()` method seems not working and the dialog will stuck there like...forever..

My code( Details simplified ):

- 1.Custom DialogFragment that extends `DialogFragment`

```java
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

private Callback callback;

// An interface for implementing functions triggered by onClick event.
public interface Callback{
   void onCancelClick();
}

// onClick event injection using butterKnife
  @OnClick(R.id.button_cancel)
    void onClick(View view) {
        callback.onCancelClick();
    }

// create a new instance
  public static MyDialogFragment newInstance() {
        MyDialogFragment fragment = new MyDialogFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

/**
   Lifecycle begins 
 */
   @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof Callback) {
            callback = (Callback) context;
        }

    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
        return dialog;
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_dialog_fragment, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        Dialog dialog = getDialog();
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    }

}
```

- 2. the host activity.

```java
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
         MyDialogFragment.Callback {

private MyDialogFragment myDialogFragment;
private boolean isTaskRunnable = false;

    /**
     *  Call some API
     */
    private void callMyApi() {

        // Create and show the dialog represents data loading.
        myDialogFragment = MyDialogFragment.newInstance();
        myDialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "myDialogFragment");

        TaskRunnable taskRunnable = new TaskRunnable<XXXXXX>() {
            @Override
            public responseList doLongOperation(params) throws MyException {
                isTaskRunnable = true;
                //...... asynchronous execution
                return //....
            }

            @Override
            public void callback(responseList response) {
                super.callback(response);
                if (isTaskRunnable) {
                    isTaskRunnable = false;

                    // dismiss the dialog (worked)
                      if (myDialogFragment != null) {
                            myDialogFragment.dismiss();
                         }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(AsyncStatus.ErrorReason reason, String msg) {
                super.onFailure(reason, msg);

                if (isTaskRunnable) {
                    isTaskRunnable = false;
                   // dismiss the dialog (worked)
                      if (myDialogFragment != null) {
                            myDialogFragment.dismiss();
                         }
                }

            }
        };

        taskRunnable.setParams(params);
        AsyncManager.runBackgroundTask(taskRunnable);

    }


/**
 * Dismiss() sometimes doesn't work
 * when I press the button immediately after openning the dialog.
 */
    @Override
    public void onCancelClick() {
        isTaskRunnable = false;
        AsyncManager.cancelAllTasks();
        myDialogFragment.dismiss();
    }

        }
```

I'd really appreciate it if anyone could help me point out the problem or give me some clues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it's not solution but pretty cheap workaround but when I have time related problem like that I just put code which causes problem inside of Handler().postDelayed(problemedFunc, 500) like that

Comment: Thanks. Very helpful! I tracked onClick event and found that I pressed the cancel button 3 times within few milliseconds... That caused the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not to answer your question but found something weird.

Should `myDialogFragment = myDialogFragment.newInstance();` be `myDialogFragment = MyDialogFragment.newInstance();`?